# Android: creating PopupMenu on android:onClick how to handle null View

Tags: java, android

There's seem to be many related question but nothing quite precisely matching. So here goes..

I have a very simple Android app with an ActionBar. That action bar contains a few menu items. When some of them are clicked, I wish to create a PopupMenu with additional options. Simple? Well, no..

Below is the relevant XML code for the ActionBar menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/main_menu" >

    ...

    <item android:id="@+id/action_options"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
          android:title="@string/mb_options"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:onClick="onPressOptions" />

</menu>
```

The onPressOptions method does get called when I press the menu button. Fine so far... However, the onPressOptions method takes MenuItem as its parameter, not a View. Creating a PopupMenu requires a View to anchor it to.

Is there any standard strategy to get some sort of a valid **View** from a **MenuItem**? Below is what I use.

```
public void onPressOptions(MenuItem mi) {
    // Get the view of the menu item
    View v = this.findViewById(R.id.action_options);

    // If we have no view!
    if(v == null) {
        // PROBLEM!!
    }

    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v); 
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.settings);
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

The above code works perfectly if the MenuItem is actually displayed in the ActionBar. If it is not, then findViewById returns null! This happens when the options menu item is the overflow. What should I do here? Is this even the correct approach to begin with?

(There are several hacks that I can employ to not make the program crash. But I'm mostly interested in the **correct** solution here..)

Edit: Anybody? Please.. One hack solution is to anchor the popupmenu to views you know are visible in the action bar. If there is, for example, one menu item with android:showAsAction="always", you can find the view of this.. This will work but this cannot be the correct way of doing things..

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_options) {
       PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
       popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.settings);
       popupMenu.show();
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will not help. You actually don't define **v** in your code above! More fundamentally, using onOptionsItemSelected does not solve the issue. I still have a MenuItem and I still need a View. (It has the same behavior as described above. If it's not in the action bar, then no View..)

Answer (score 0):

One potential "solution" is to define submenus in the menu XML file.

```
<item android:title="options">
    <menu>
        <item android:title="action1" />
        <item android:title="action2" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

This is suitable for some scenarios, and most importantly, is not a hack and is guaranteed to work. (This is, however, not the specific answer I was looking for..)